# Automated email after event registration

Tags: civievent, civimail

We have an email with instructions about our event, information to help you prepare, hotel information, etc. Currently we're adding it all to the receipt, which makes for a very long message. We'd rather have it sent out as a separate message. Especially seeing as some of our events have different information and we have to include everything in one message, even if it doesn't apply to that event.

Is there a way to have an automated message that goes out after a registration that is not the receipt? Or a way to add to the reminder emails the option for a **certain amount of time after registration**, not time before/after the event?

Thanks!

Oh, I'm on Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.7.29

[image: Scheduled Reminder - training Name]

[image: Scheduled Reminder - training Type]

Answer (score 3):

You can use Scheduled Reminders (**Administer>Communication>Scheduled Reminders**) to automatically send an email based on an event type, or even event name.

Alternatively you can use the CiviRules extension(extension found here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules and documenation here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/) to do achieve this.

Comment: The scheduled reminders for events are all based on an amount of time before/after the event's beginning and end dates. I want to be able to use the registration date so that we can send the information out shortly after they register. I tried CiviRules, but couldn't find anything about sending an email in the actions. That was actually the first thing I tried.

Comment: You also need to install the Email API extension to enable the sending of email! You can find it here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if I missed something somewhere.  :)

Comment: Ah, I see why I missed it - it's not there for version 4.7 of CiviCRM.

Comment: Hi Jenni, AFAIK it does work on CiviCRM 4.7

Comment: It only lists through 4.6 on the page and it's not available on the extensions page inside Civi. I guess I could try it out on the dev site, but I'm extremely hesitant to install something on our live site that isn't made for the version we're running.

Comment: I would never recommend installing something on live without testing whatever the status of the extension :-) So certainly try it on dev first. But I have it running on 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried, just a thought:

You are using an Event Page, so can you make a contribution type reminder which triggers some hrs(eg 2) after the `receive_date`?

[image]

By this, When a new event registration happens, a contribution is recorded for the contact and after 2 hrs - the reminder mail would be triggered containing stuffs for preparation, etc.

Note that this would send reminder for every contribution with financial type = `Event Fee` (selected in the second multi-select box) financial type. If you want to avoid that, you might need to create a custom financial type from `Administer -> CiviContribute -> Financial Type` for this Event Page.

If the above doesn't work, maybe you should proceed in writing an extension and use postProcess() hook on Event confirm page and send a mail using a custom message template.

Comment: So I'd have to create a contribution type for each one of our event types? Unfortunately writing an extension is beyond my expertise. It's really too bad it isn't already there - I'm sure I can't be the only one who could really use something like this.

Comment: How about creating Schedule reminders using Event Name?

Comment: Scheduled reminders when it comes to Events are scheduled based on the event's start/end dates. I need to be able to set it according to when someone registers. For instance, an hour after they've registered. Essentially it would go out shortly after they get their receipt.

Comment: @JenniSimonis did you ever reach a resolution on this?

Comment: No, we've just continued to keep it all in the receipt instead.